# Converting an HTML page to a PDF yields extremely imperfect miscalculations

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I have an HTML page with 96px high elements.

I set the attributes in CSS, I measure them with screenshots in Photoshop, I inspect them in the inspector. They are 96px high.

When printing this page using various methods (Chrome in-browser "save to PDF" functionality, wkhtmltopdf, services online, etc.), they stop being 96px high.

I'm led to believe the process of converting HTML to a PDF isn't a pixel perfect one, and this is understandable.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Below are source HTML files and output PDF files.

```css
body {
  width: 8.5in;
  margin-top: 0.3in;
  margin-left: 0.2in;
}
.label {
  width: 2.625in;
  height: 1in;
  margin-right: .125in;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
@page {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="label">

    <small>1-pack</small>
  </div>

  <div class="label">

    <small>1-pack</small>
  </div>

  <div class="label">

    <small>1-pack</small>
  </div>

  <div class="label">

    <small>1-pack</small>
  </div>

  <div class="label">

    <small>1-pack</small>
  </div>

  <div class="label">

    <small>1-pack</small>
  </div>

  <div class="label">

    <small>1-pack</small>
  </div>

  <div class="label">

    <small>1-pack</small>
  </div>

  <div class="label">

    <small>1-pack</small>
  </div>

  <div class="label">

    <small>1-pack</small>
  </div>

  <div class="label">

    <small>1-pack</small>
  </div>

  <div class="label">

    <small>1-pack</small>
  </div>

  <div class="label">

    <small>1-pack</small>
  </div>

  <div class="label">

    <small>1-pack</small>
  </div>

  <div class="label">

    <small>1-pack</small>
  </div>

  <div class="label">

    <small>1-pack</small>
  </div>

  <div class="label">

    <small>1-pack</small>
  </div>

  <div class="label">

    <small>1-pack</small>
  </div>

  <div class="label">

    <small>1-pack</small>
  </div>

  <div class="label">

    <small>1-pack</small>
  </div>

  <div class="label">

    <small>1-pack</small>
  </div>

  <div class="label">

    <small>1-pack</small>
  </div>

  <div class="label">

    <small>1-pack</small>
  </div>

  <div class="label">

    <small>1-pack</small>
  </div>

  <div class="label">

    <small>1-pack</small>
  </div>

  <div class="label">

    <small>1-pack</small>
  </div>

  <div class="label">

    <small>1-pack</small>
  </div>

  <div class="label">

    <small>1-pack</small>
  </div>

  <div class="label">

    <small>1-pack</small>
  </div>

  <div class="label">

    <small>1-pack</small>
  </div>

</body>
```

http://docdro.id/R4OLmTz

Comment: If you need to have pixel perfect measurements then exporting your page to a `png` would be a workaround.

Comment: wkhtmltopdf allows excellent control of the output.  Check the documentation to see how you can use it. http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt

Comment: Why would you want them pixel-perfect in the first place? Maybe there's a workaround for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: your screen is probably 96ppi, your printer certainly have a higher dpi. Instead of px, use in, cm or pt units. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch

Comment: @Kaiido If you look at the source above, I do use pixels.

Comment: @Alex I don't want pixel perfect, but I don't want it to lose the ability to align properly after the second row... as displayed in the example.

Comment: @user2182349 That's the equivalent of "let me Google that for you". I've tried all of the command line options and even linked to the output of them not working...

Comment: @lleaff How can I export from HTML to PNG?

Comment: @BrandonRos, hence I recommended you to **not** use px.

Comment: @BrandonRos - My intent was not 'let me Google that for you' - I have worked with wkhtmltopdf and was able to get excellent results by **studying** (not just reading) the documentation and using the options to customize the output.  I was only trying to let you know that what you wanted to do is probably possible with the tool.

Comment: @user218349 For what it is worth, I had to use wkhtmltoimage, which doesn't obey the CSS `page-break` rule, so I had to write my only solution to chop up the pages. Not the two best pieces of software at the moment.